# Creation of a new Android application in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have Eclipse IDE 2020-09 on a Windows 10 laptop with JDK 14.0.2.
When I create a new Android application, even with the default SDK values in the wizard, the finish button remains disabled. Also the import and run of an Android app fails linked to `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) is the officially supported IDE for Android development. Using this instead of Eclipse will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Yes thanks. I know well. But it is too heavy - requires 8 GB RAM. I have only 4 GB on my laptop. I want to find a solution for Eclipse.